# Decode Google Oauth2 Access Token with Javascript

Tags: javascript, oauth, google-api-client

I want to display all the information in an access token (given_name, family_name, email, userid....) given by google oauth2 with javascript.

Is there a good example/demo where this is already done? If not, what is the best way to decode the access token you get when you log in with javascript on oauth2.

I found this example that displays name and profile picture, but I don't understand how they did it:
(http://www.gethugames.in/blog/2012/04/authentication-and-authorization-for-google-apis-in-javascript-popup-window-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 1):

That information isn't in the token, which is just that, a token used as proof of authorization, and which for most or all Google API's needs to be refreshed hourly. The token is proof that the user has authorized Google to give that information to the program.

In that example step 5, the call to getUserInfo() passes the token back to Google. For the call to work, and to get the info, the user must have previously granted that permission:

```
USERINFO_SCOPE: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
```

The permission is tied to the application, as is the authorization.

Comment: In step 5 they use this to get the name and picture:
                    $('#uName').append(user.name);
                    $('#imgHolder').attr('src', user.picture);
But what is .append and .attr?

Comment: Ah, that's jquery... it's just appending the user's name to an html element with an id of 'uName', and setting the source attribute of an image that has an id of 'imgHolder' to the user's picture link. (http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_append.asp)

Comment: Still having a hard time with this code. Are there any other better examples that use only JS?

Comment: Keep googling. They've got vast quantities of documentation playgrounds and examples hidden under (https://developers.google.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can Decode via this function-

```
const {OAuth2Client} = require('google-auth-library');
const client = new OAuth2Client(CLIENT_ID);
async function verify() {
  const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
      idToken: token,
      audience: CLIENT_ID,
  });
  const payload = ticket.getPayload();
  const userid = payload['sub'];
  console.log(userid);

}
verify().catch(console.error);
```

Output is :-

```
{ iss: 'accounts.google.com',
  azp:
   '89838985845-261g3g9ob1244uvajvvj4fkueehhdfhsj.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  aud:
   '89838985845-261g3g9ob1244uvajvvj4fkueehhdfhsj.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  sub: '1001728418648724577297',
  email: 'rajputankit22@gmail.com',
  email_verified: true,
  at_hash: 'y0_OmfSbg-iHOq__Km-5kw',
  name: 'Ankit Kumar Rajpoot',
  picture:
   'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AAuE7mBrCW_ubLUHpnqwQZ1DvLDb9E4IHxfy43K6amNwt1Q=s96-c',
  given_name: 'Ankit',
  family_name: 'Kumar Rajpoot',
  locale: 'en',
  iat: 1580591026,
  exp: 1580594626,
  jti: 'fbbfca7sghsdhjfghsdfgh74888jhsd88s986d9876b30d' }
```